# Preg_match if a string beginns with "00"{number} or "+"{number}

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have to test if a string begins with **00** or with **+**.

<sub>*pseudocode:*</sub>

```
Say I have the string **0090** or **+41** 
if the string begins with **0090** return true,  
elseif string begins  with **+90** replace the **+** with **00**  
else return false
```

The last two digits can be from 0-9.
How do I do that in php?

Comment: <s> if(preg_match("!^(?:00|\+)(?:\d\d)!", $input) > 0) { } </s> See codaddict's [answer](#2536697).

Comment: @streetparade Thanks for selecting my answer, but take a look at the answer by codaddict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
function check(&$input) { // takes the input by reference.
    if(preg_match('#^00\d{2}#',$input)) { // input begins with "00"
        return true;
    } elseif(preg_match('#^\+\d{2}#',$input)) { // input begins with "+"
        $input = preg_replace('#^\+#','00',$input); // replace + with 00.
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (substr($str, 0, 2) === '00')
{
    return true;
}
elseif ($str[0] === '+')
{
    $str = '00'.substr($str, 1);
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

The middle condition won't do anything though, unless $str is a reference.

Comment: can i alos do it with a regex i did iwth this cond. 
if(!preg_match("#^(\+|00){\d,2}#",$str)

Comment: Why are you asking me if you can do it, when the next sentence says you have done it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (substr($theString, 0, 4) === '0090') {
  return true;
} else if (substr($theString, 0, 3) === '+90') {
  $theString = '00' . substr($theString, 1);
  return true;
} else
  return false;
```